# Angular2 Nativescript: auto-reformatting TextInput with ngModelChange - why does this not work?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to reformat user input into a text field as it is entered. For example, let's say I want to limit the input to digits, and implement a maxLength of 4 characters, and prepend it with a "+" sign for the display.

I'm doing a little more reformatting IRL but this should do for an example ...

```
export class MyComponent {
    private _myField: string;
    myFieldDisplay: string;

    onMyFieldDisplayChange(event) {
        // I can see the display field has the correct value here
        console.log(this.myFieldDisplay);

        this._myField = event.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, 4);
        this.myFieldDisplay = "+" + this._myField;

        // and I can see the display field has the correct value here
        console.log(this.myFieldDisplay);
    }
}
```

Here is my template code:

```
<TextField 
    [ngModel]="myFieldDisplay" 
    (ngModelChange)="onMyFieldDisplayChange($event)">
</TextField>
```

What I expect is that it will store the private variable `_myField`, reformat `myFieldDisplay` and always display the reformatted value of `myFieldDisplay` in the TextField.

What happens is - I can see that `myFieldDisplay` is always reformatted correctly in the console, but this is not always reflected in the TextField.  The TextField always allows more than 4 characters, and it only seems to strip out non-numeric characters on the *first change*. I.e., it only works, and only *sometimes*, on the first keypress if the entered character is non-numeric. Also, the "+" sign remains visible.

It's boggling my mind to log `myFieldDisplay` to the console, see that it *always* has the correct value, but not see that reflected in the TextField.

I've tried using this [NativeScript Masked Input](https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-maskedinput) plugin, but it doesn't quite fit my use case, I'd like stricter validation.

What gives? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Is there a much much easier way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing?

For what it's worth, I'm pretty new to NativeScript, TypeScript, Angular2 and mobile app development so ... I won't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: If you tap a button or something like that in another place of the screen after you change the text, the TextField gets the update?

Comment: on your function  onMyFieldDisplayChange(event) the event will display the changes in the text field. Try logging console.log(event) in the function then you'll get the changes in the text field.for the masked input lib. here's how I managed to format text field https://github.com/dlucidone/nativescript-maskedinput-example

Comment: @Dlucidone I've actually seen your repo before! But like I said, I've already tried that `maskedinput` library and it's not going to work for my use case

Comment: @EileenNoonan Wat you are asking is easy with ngModelchange.Where are u stuck?Could you explain a bit your use case.

Comment: @Dlucidone My use case is pretty similar to any other input masking. I just can't get it working in NativeScript. `ngModelChange` is not working. Unless I'm somehow using it incorrectly? Hence the question ... the above code sample produces the errors described. If I could get that working, then I should in theory be able to get my actual code working.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working like this -

#### HTML

```
 <TextField id="checkingPhoneNumber" (ngModelChange)="PhoneNumberCheck($event)" hint="Phone Number" keyboardType="number" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" returnKeyType="next" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"></TextField>
```

#### TS

```
 `import textFieldModule = require("ui/text-field");
 import observableModule = require("data/observable");

 PhoneNumberCheck(args){
 var TextInputView = this.page.getViewById<TextField>("checkingPhone");
 TextInputView.on(textFieldModule.TextField.propertyChangeEvent,function(eventData:observableModule.PropertyChangeData){
  if (eventData.propertyName == "text" && eventData.value.length > 10) {
   setTimeout(
     function() { 
      TextInputView.text = eventData.value.substr(0, 10);
    }, 0);
  }
  });
  }`
```

Here in this the text field input will get substring as soon as it reaches the text length of 10.

Answer (score 0):

@Elleen Noonan to use two-way binding in Angular-2 you need to import the FormsModule and to be more specific in NativeScript you need to import the wrapper called **NativeScriptFormsModule** in the respective @NgModule

e.g.
To use [this two-way binding](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/d2c54685f9c38873d00996968b7acdf55f872495/app/ui-category/button/binding-text/binding-text.component.html#L3) we needed to [import the NativeScriptFormsModule here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/d2c54685f9c38873d00996968b7acdf55f872495/app/ui-category/button/button-examples.module.ts#L39)

More about two-way binding [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-data-binding.html#data-binding)

Comment: I am importing NativeScript's forms module and have always done so. I am new to NS etc but I've got several other forms in this app already working with two-way data binding.